# Error when installing prophet package in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to install the prophet package in python, but it gives the following error. Can you please help?

It is required for the darts package. Actually, the main goal is to install the darts package but it gives an error when it comes to installing prophet as a sub-package. So, when I try installing prophet separately, I cannot.

In Anaconda prompt in windows, I do:

```
pip install prophet
```

The error is:

````
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/fa/c382f0ac5abe9f0a4df9d874a5e8843db035fe2f071b5c00a545b1e3c10b/prophet-1.0.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.22 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from prophet) (0.29.12)
Requirement already satisfied: cmdstanpy==0.9.68 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from prophet) (0.9.68)
Requirement already satisfied: pystan~=2.19.1.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from prophet) (2.19.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in c:\users\r.soltani\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from prophet) (1.21.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.0.4 in c:\users\r.soltani\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from prophet) (1.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=2.0.0 in c:\users\r.soltani\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from prophet) (3.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: LunarCalendar>=0.0.9 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from prophet) (0.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: convertdate>=2.1.2 in c:\users\r.soltani\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from prophet) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: holidays>=0.10.2 in c:\users\r.soltani\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from prophet) (0.13)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools-git>=1.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from prophet) (1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from prophet) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.36.1 in c:\users\r.soltani\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from prophet) (4.64.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ujson in c:\users\r.soltani\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from cmdstanpy==0.9.68->prophet) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=1.0.4->prophet) (2019.1)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in c:\users\r.soltani\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->prophet) (4.33.2)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in c:\users\r.soltani\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->prophet) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->prophet) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->prophet) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\users\r.soltani\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->prophet) (9.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->prophet) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ephem>=3.7.5.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from LunarCalendar>=0.0.9->prophet) (4.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pymeeus<=1,>=0.3.13 in c:\users\r.soltani\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from convertdate>=2.1.2->prophet) (0.5.11)
Requirement already satisfied: hijri-converter in c:\users\r.soltani\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from holidays>=0.10.2->prophet) (2.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: korean-lunar-calendar in c:\users\r.soltani\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from holidays>=0.10.2->prophet) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.0->prophet) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama; platform_system == "Windows" in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tqdm>=4.36.1->prophet) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib>=2.0.0->prophet) (41.0.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: prophet
  Building wheel for prophet (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\REDD2~1.SOL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-install-lmtfq4_i\\prophet\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\REDD2~1.SOL\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-wheel-8b3_ugik' --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib
  creating build\lib\prophet
  creating build\lib\prophet\stan_model
  C:\Users\r.soltani\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py:138: UserWarning: Pandas requires version '2.7.0' or newer of 'numexpr' (version '2.6.9' currently installed).
    warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
  INFO:pystan:COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9 NOW.
  WARNING:pystan:MSVC compiler is not supported
  stanfit4anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9_8617278733964175527.cpp
  C:\Users\r.soltani\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/prim/mat/meta/seq_view.hpp(145): warning C4267: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/prim/mat/fun/multiply_lower_tri_self_transpose.hpp(19): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>::Index' to 'int', possible loss of data
          with
          [
              Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>
          ]
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/prim/mat/fun/multiply_lower_tri_self_transpose.hpp(27): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>::Index' to 'int', possible loss of data
          with
          [
              Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>
          ]```

I cannot share the whole error because of the character limit here.
````

Comment: Add a pastebin with full error

Comment: Sorry, what is a Pastebin? I cannot add the full error due to the space limit.

Answer (score 0):

This is used for installing prophet from conda ->

> `conda install -c conda-forge prophet`

using pip ->

> `pip install prophet`

or

install pystan and fbprophet ->

`pip install pystan~=2.14`

`pip install fbprophet`